# passing multiple values using xmlhttp.send

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to pass two different values into an `XMLHttpRequestObject.send` but cannot seem to get the php script to read them both, it will only read the first value passed. How can I get the **PHP** to read both the values, here is the sample code:

**HTML**

```
  <select id="mes" onchange="callCourseYards(this);">
  <option>-</option>
  </select>
```

**Javascript**

```
  var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  function callCourseYards(selectObject){

        if(XMLHttpRequestObject){

        XMLHttpRequestObject.open("POST", "php/CourseChoiceTeeOff.php");

        XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200){
                var returnData = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;

                var messageDiv = document.getElementById('tee');
                messageDiv.innerHTML = returnData;

            }   
        }

        var data = selectObject.value;
        var course = selectObject.value;
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send("data=" + data + "course=" + course);

    }
    return false;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $pdo_dsn='localhost';
    $dbname ='XXX';
    $mysql_user='XXX';
    $mysql_pass='XXX';

    $db = mysqli_connect($pdo_dsn, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $dbname);

    if(!$db){
        print "Unable to connect to MySQL";
    }

    $myData = $_POST['data'];
    $myData1 = $_POST['course'];

    $sql_state = "SELECT * FROM ".$myData1." WHERE CourseCode = '".$myData."' ORDER BY CourseCode";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_state);

    $out = "";
    $myrowcount = 0;

    if(!$result){
        $out = "Error";
    }else{

        $out = "<option>Selecciona un campo</option><br/ >";
        $numresults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numresults; $i++){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $teeOff = $row['TeeOff'];
            $out .= "<option id='".$myData."' value='".$teeOff."'> ".$teeOff."</option>";
        } 
        $out .= "<br/ >";
    }

    print $out; 
?>
```

I cannot seem to get the values through the `XMLHttpRequestObject` to go through into the **PHP**. I am not sure if its the syntax or how they should get past into the **PHP**.

I have tried using the & and the + symbols to concatenate both values, but I am not sure if this is possible. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem? I need both values to be able to do the **mySQL** search in the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `"data=" + data + "&course=" + course` perhaps - though, you do need to be sure `data` and `course` are url encoded too

Comment: just noticed your code says `var data = selectObject.value;
        var course = selectObject.value;` ... so, data and course are the same?

Comment: Thankyou, I figured it out at last. Had to do with how the attribute was getting passed through the function. Like you mentioned in your second comment. Thanks for your help.